# Where are the instructions for running OpenRewrite receipes when my build is not in maven or gradle

Tags: openrewrite

I have a build that uses ant
I want to run some OpenRewrite reciepes against it

Previously there was this page that described how I could do that (it was there a week ago):
https://docs.openrewrite.org/running-recipes/running-rewrite-without-build-tool-plugins
That page is gone now.
Does anyone know if I can run OpenRewrite receipes against an ant build?

Answer (score 3):

We've recently removed that page as it had not been updated since the moved to Rewrite 8. We [now recommend](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-docs/issues/244#issuecomment-1806799876) folks to [use the Moderne CLI](https://docs.moderne.io/user-documentation/getting-started/cli-intro) when using neither Maven nor Gradle.

Ant is not supported officially, but I know of at least two community members who got recipe runs to work for Ant. Feel free to [join our Slack](https://join.slack.com/t/rewriteoss/shared_invite/zt-nj42n3ea-b%7E62rIHzb3Vo0E1APKCXEA) and I'll try to put you in touch there. I don't know how far they got in terms of resolving dependencies, as I didn't yet see any outcome shared there.

Also, just this past week, we had a community member wire up projects built with headless Eclipse; he might also have some insights to share with you regarding how to get things running on Rewrite 8.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Can you provide the link to that page?  Granted, it may be out of date, but it still could have value.

Comment: Sure; here's the link: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-docs/pull/245
If you manage to get it working for Ant please let us know and share your approach, for instance on our Slack. Perhaps we can make support official